# How to create monthly periods in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have monthly data, and I would like to add another column for the period. The column would say M01 for January, M02 for February, M03 for March, and so on. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I have:

```
unemployment = data.frame(Month = c("Sept 2002", "Oct 2002", "Nov 2002", "Dec 2002", "Jan 2003", "Feb 2003"), 
                   Total = c(5.7, 5.7, 5.9, 
6, 5.8, 5.9))

> unemployment

      Month Total
1 Sept 2002   5.7
2  Oct 2002   5.7
3  Nov 2002   5.9
4  Dec 2002   6.0
5  Jan 2003   5.8
6  Feb 2003   5.9
```

This is what I want:

```
      Month Period Total
1 Sept 2002 M09      5.7
2  Oct 2002 M10      5.7
3  Nov 2002 M11      5.9
4  Dec 2002 M12      6.0
5  Jan 2003 M01      5.8
6  Feb 2003 M02      5.9
```

**EDIT**
Updated code to show all 12 months

```
structure(list(Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June"
), Year = c("2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003"), 
    Unemp_percent = c(5.8, 5.9, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.3)), row.names = 5:10, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
unemployment %>% 
  mutate(Period = case_when(grepl("Jan",Month) ~ "M01",
                            grepl("Feb",Month) ~ "M02",
                            grepl("Mar",Month) ~ "M03",
                            grepl("Apr",Month) ~ "M04",
                            grepl("May",Month) ~ "M05",
                            grepl("June",Month) ~ "M06",
                            grepl("July",Month) ~ "M07",
                            grepl("Aug",Month) ~ "M08",
                            grepl("Sept",Month) ~ "M09",
                            grepl("Oct",Month) ~ "M10",
                            grepl("Nov",Month) ~ "M11",
                            grepl("Dec",Month) ~ "M12"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mutate` and `gsub` and `match` the first 3 letters with the built in `month.abb` data

```
library(dplyr)

unemployment |> 
  mutate(.after = Month,  
Period = paste0("M", match(gsub("(.{3})(.*)", "\\1", Month ), month.abb)))
```

```
      Month Period Total
1 Sept 2002     M9   5.7
2  Oct 2002    M10   5.7
3  Nov 2002    M11   5.9
4  Dec 2002    M12   6.0
5  Jan 2003     M1   5.8
6  Feb 2003     M2   5.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here´s another alternative:

```
unemployment %>% 
  mutate(month = gsub("(^.{3}).*", "\\1", Month),
         Period = paste0("M", as.numeric(factor(x$month, month.abb)))) %>% 
  select(Month, Period, Total)
```

Output:

```
      Month Period Total
1 Sept 2002     M9   5.7
2  Oct 2002    M10   5.7
3  Nov 2002    M11   5.9
4  Dec 2002    M12   6.0
5  Jan 2003     M1   5.8
6  Feb 2003     M2   5.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a reference table of months and periods, then `left_join`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

months <- data.frame(mo = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                     Period = paste0("M", 1:12))

unemployment %>%
  mutate(mo = str_extract(Month, "^[:alpha:]+")) %>%
  left_join(months, by = "mo")

      Month Total   mo Period
1 Sept 2002   5.7 Sept     M9
2  Oct 2002   5.7  Oct    M10
3  Nov 2002   5.9  Nov    M11
4  Dec 2002   6.0  Dec    M12
5  Jan 2003   5.8  Jan     M1
6  Feb 2003   5.9  Feb     M2
```

Comment: Hi! I just tried this, but it gives NA's for March and April in my full data set. Let me update the code to show all 12 months.

Comment: Just fixed the abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 4th character of the Month column if it is a word character giving a standard 3 month abbreviation for the month.  Then convert that to a yearmon object and format it in the desired way.  At the end we relocate the Period column to be after the Month column.  If it is not important that the Period column come after the Month column then omit the last line of code.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

unemployment %>%
  mutate(Period = format(as.yearmon(sub("^(...)\\w?", "\\1", Month)), "M%m")) %>%
  relocate(Period, .after = Month)
```

giving:

```
      Month Period Total
1 Sept 2002    M09   5.7
2  Oct 2002    M10   5.7
3  Nov 2002    M11   5.9
4  Dec 2002    M12   6.0
5  Jan 2003    M01   5.8
6  Feb 2003    M02   5.9
```